# Gradient of a Vector Field Without Coordinates

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

For a scalar field $ \phi $, we have the "coordinate-free" definition in terms of the exterior derivative:
$$ \nabla \phi = \ (\mathrm d \phi)^\flat := \ \langle \mathrm d \phi, \cdot \rangle $$

However, in trying to derive some vector calculus identities, I came into a bit of trouble in finding an expression for the gradient of a vector field $A$. I tried $ (\mathrm dA^{\sharp})^\flat $ but this doesn't seem to work out when you do a simple example in coordinates.

Is there a good simple formulation of this somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're switching the isomorphisms $\flat$ and $\sharp$ everywhere, but in any case: $d(A^\flat)$ is a $2$-form, not a $1$-form, so you can't hit that with $\sharp$. If this is happening on a $3$-dim manifold, the metric gives you the Hodge star, and then $\star(d(A^\flat))$ is a vector field: the curl of $A$.

Comment: Use `\sharp` and `\flat`, not `#` and `b`. Also use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`.